# ASP.NET Core MVC application expires despite having valid cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application, set up with cookie authentication. I am trying to figure out how to configure the application so that the logged in session lasts for longer than an hour. I am using .NET 6.

In my `ConfigureServices` method in `startup.cs` I have the following:

```
   services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "/Login";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Error/AccessDenied";

        });

       
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("TemplateAdmin", policy => policy.RequireRole("Administrator", "Helpdesk-Admin"));
        });

                   
        //set up session
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        
        services.AddMvc(x=>x.EnableEndpointRouting=false);
```

In the `Configure` method I have this code:

```
            app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/Index"); //handle 404 errors
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseSession(new SessionOptions(){Cookie = new CookieBuilder(){Name = ".AspNetCore.Session.MyApp",Expiration = TimeSpan.FromHours(12)}});
            app.UseAsmEnvironmentMiddleware();
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "user",
                    template: "{controller=User}/{action=Edit}/{userName}");
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");       
            });

            app.UseCookiePolicy(); //important that this comes after UseMvc otherwise session/tempdata will not work
```

And then I also have some code in the login action

```
await m_HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal,new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(12),
                IsPersistent = true
            });
```

So the result of this is that after login, there are 2 cookies which seem to control the Session information:

```
.AspNetCore.Cookies
.AspNetCore.Session.MyApp
```

Despite this, after an hour or so, if I navigate to a route it will redirect to the login page, despite the above 2 cookies still showing an expiry date in the future (as viewed in Chrome devtools).

Any ideas how to make this logged in session persist for longer? I had thought that it was the session cookie that controlled the redirect behaviour.

Some additional information, when the session has apparently expired(ie the cookies are not expired, but I get redirected to the login page), if I trigger the following code, the session cookies seem to work again:

```
this.HttpContext.Session.SetString(Constants.CurrentEnvironment, environment);
```

Comment: Are you using IIS?

Comment: No it is self hosted

Comment: Ok, I dont know if it could be a similar issue - but when using IIS you should set Load User Profile=true - Otherwise this behavior occurs

Comment: Does it still work if you recycle the app within the timeframe?

Comment: Is your browser in the same timezone with your server? a related issue:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31526507/when-will-my-cookie-actually-expire